# What is the multiplatform alternative to subprocess.getstatusoutput (older commands.setstatusoutput() from Python?

Tags: python, redirect, process

The code below is outdated in Python 3.0 by being replaced by `subprocess.getstatusoutput()`.

```
import commands
(ret, out) = commands.getstatusoutput('some command')
print ret
print out
```

The real question is what's the multiplatform alternative to this command from Python because the above code does fail ugly under Windows because getstatusoutput is supported only under Unix and Python does not tell you this, instead you get something like:

```
>test.py
1
'{' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be the multiplatform implementation for getstatusoutput():

```
def getstatusoutput(cmd): 
    """Return (status, output) of executing cmd in a shell."""
    """This new implementation should work on all platforms."""
    import subprocess
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)  
    output = "".join(pipe.stdout.readlines()) 
    sts = pipe.returncode
    if sts is None: sts = 0
    return sts, output
```

Comment: works for me on Windows Python 2.7 -- MANY THANKS FOR THIS CODE MASTERPIECE

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't really consider this *multiplatform*, but you can use `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess
pipe = subprocess.Popen('dir', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
output = pipe.stdout.readlines()
sts = pipe.wait()
print sts
print output
```

---

Here's a drop-in replacement for `getstatusoutput`:

```
def getstatusoutput(cmd): 
    """Return (status, output) of executing cmd in a shell."""
    """This new implementation should work on all platforms."""
    import subprocess
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = str.join("", pipe.stdout.readlines()) 
    sts = pipe.wait()
    if sts is None:
        sts = 0
    return sts, output
```

This snippet was proposed by the original poster.  I made some changes since  `getstatusoutput` duplicates `stderr` onto `stdout`.

---

The problem is that `dir` isn't really a multiplatform call but [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) allows you to execute shell commands on any platform.  I would steer clear of using shell commands unless you absolutely need to.  Investigate the contents of the [`os`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/os.html), [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/os.path.html), and [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/shutil.html) packages instead.

```
import os
import os.path
for rel_name in os.listdir(os.curdir):
  abs_name = os.path.join(os.curdir, rel_name)
  if os.path.isdir(abs_name):
    print('DIR:  ' + rel_name)
  elif os.path.isfile(abs_name):
    print('FILE: ' + rel_name)
  else:
    print('UNK?  ' + rel_name)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you did not used community wiki option because I was not able to update your answer. I added another one instead.

Comment: It is marked as a community wiki, but I think that your reputation has to exceed 100 before you can edit ;)

Comment: Ooh, In this case can you update your solution with the code I posted on the last answer so I can accept the response and cleanup the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

getstatusoutput docs say it runs the command like so:

{ cmd } 2>&1

Which obviously doesn't work with cmd.exe (the 2>&1 works fine if you need it though).

You can use Popen as above, but also include the parameter 'stderr=subprocess.STDOUT' to get the same behaviour as getstatusoutput.

My tests on Windows had returncode set to None though, which is not ideal if you're counting on the return value.